# Create Graphs for the outcome of a Fair Coin Tossed 3 times with JULIA or Python

Tags: python, julia

I am creating this code with JULIA and GraphRecipes. But it seems really ugly and far from what I wanted here:

[image: 1]

this is the code:

```
using GraphRecipes, Plots
gr()
default(size=(800, 400))

g = [0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0; 
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0; 
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0;]
graphplot(g, fontsize=12, names="H".*string.(1:14), nodeshape=:circle)
```

I believe if JULIA is till too young maybe there is Python code that can create this, maybe even for more than 3 times tossed, it will be good, along with the code to calculate the probability for each outcome will be nice. I am open to either JULIA or Python solution for this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably rather want a tool like https://silverdecisions.pl/ for this

Comment: If you create a decision tree with Silverdecisions.pl (this will be just a JSON) you can process it programmatically with this Python library: https://github.com/pszufe/chondro   See the examples at the README of that project.

Comment: I see silverdecisions.pl but some people already post what I want to create in Julia Discourse. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing you can do is make `g` programatically. For example

```
g = zeros(Int, 14, 14)
for i in 1:3
    g[i, 2i] = 1
    g[i, 2i+1] = 1
    g[i+7, 2i+7] = 1
    g[i+7, 2i+8] = 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This user addresses the same question here and on julia discourse, without mentioning it. https://discourse.julialang.org/t/probability-outcomes-plot-with-julia-for-fair-coin-tossing/94663    He takes a partial answer received here and post it on julia discourse, as being  his partial result.  It is not fair!
There he says that Julia is amazing, here that it is an immature language and maybe Python is most suitable for his task.

Comment: yes Julia is an amazing language, Python discourse is not as responsive as Julia Discourse. It is open source language, I sometimes mention SoF in Discourse and vice versa, forget me if not always. Sometimes type in a hurry.

Comment: What is it that is not fair? I never take the credit, nothing is wrong by learning programming language, if I don't know I ask in a lot of places.

Comment: "if I don't know I ask in a lot of places. " - you should add links to the other places you ask. Otherwise people could spend time on answering in one place without realising that it's already been answered in the orher.